# Prove that for a polynomial function $f$ if $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, then $f(x) + f'(x) + \cdots + f^{(n)} (x) \geq 0$

Tags: analysis

Prove that for a polynomial function $f$ with degree $n$ if $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$, then $f(x) + f'(x) + \cdots + f^{(n)} (x) \geq 0$.

Give me some hints for this and please explain to me how you have come to those hints.

Comment: I believe you should specify that $n=\deg f$, since it is not true otherwise.

Comment: you can see this  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397973/sum-of-polynoms-of-given-property/397997#397997

Comment: sorry guys, I just edited

Comment: Yes I see this is a duplicate. So should I delete this question? By the way, the solution there seems ingenious. How on earth can I think of it?

Comment: @julypraise : you don't have o delete it, it will be closed if there are 2 more votes to close... As you said it may sound as if it is ingenious... wait for some time some one might help you...

Comment: have you tried seeing this by considering degree $1$ and degree $2$ polynomials separately... ? this may not be generalized but then i was expecting you may get some idea...

Comment: Yes, I think those simple cases may motivate one to think of the second solution on the linked page. But I never thought of use of $e^x$.

Comment: @math110 How did you think of use of $e^x$ in such a way? Is it some kind of general technique in analysis, in measure theory, etc..?