# prove that $(p+p'+...+ p^{(n)}) \geq 0 $

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $\forall x \in \mathbb R, \quad  p(x) \geq 0$ where $p$ is a polynomial of order $n$  prove that ,

> $$(p+p'+...+ p^{(n)})  \geq 0 \quad (\forall x \in \mathbb R) $$

explain : I tried induction on $n$ and taylor expansion to find a relation between coefficients .

Comment: Polynomial with real coefficients, yes?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599655/prove-that-for-a-polynomial-function-f-if-fx-geq-0-for-all-x-then-fx?rq=1

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397973/sum-of-polynoms-of-given-property

Comment: in question did not mentioned this point but i think yes, the polynomial has real coefficients.