# Ques . Related to derivative and proving an inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality

Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ and for all $x$, $p(x) >= 0$. Show that for all $x$,
$$p(x)+p'(x)+...+ p^{(n)}(x) >= 0$$

My approach for this question is like this:

Assume $p(x)$ is increasing so $p'(x)>0$ and in a similar way imply $p'(x)$ is increasing until the $n$th derivative of $p$ i.e. $p^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$ then just add and complete the proof.

But, I know my approach is vague and my professor would destroy me if I told him this solution. Can you please help me with it or suggest a better but rigorous way of doing it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $p$ needs not be increasing, see $x^2+x+1$. In point of fact, **no** positive polynomial can be increasing (unless it's constant). Also, for all polynomials of degree $\ge2$ at least one of $p$ or $p'$ isn't increasing.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397973/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p(x)%2Bp%27(x)%2B...%2B%20p%5E%7B(n)%7D(x)%20%5Cge%200%24)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** If $q(x)=p(x)+\ldots+p^{(n)}(x)$, what can you say about $q'(x)-q(x)$ ?

Comment: Also just want to note that for any $k>n$, $p^{(k)}(x) = 0$ because this is an $n$-degree polynomial.

Comment: I am still stuck with your hint ... Can you elaborate a little more please

Comment: @randomguy47 $q'-q = -p \le 0$, hence $(e^{-x}q(x))'\le 0$. Can you take it  from here?