# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 11, Problem 26: What exactly is being asked to be proved?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> 26. Suppose $f$ is a polynomial function of degree $n$ with $f \geq 0$ (so $n$ must be even). Prove that $f+f'+f''+...+f^{(n)} \geq 0$.

My interpretation is that we are asked to prove

$$\begin{array}{l} f \text{ polynomial degree n} \\ \forall x, f(x)\geq 0\end{array} \implies\forall x, f(x)+f'(x)+...+f^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$$

Is this interpretation correct?

The solution manual solution is as follows

> The minimum of $f+f'+...+f^{(n)}$ occurs at a point where
> $0=f'+f''+...+f^{(n)}$ [the next term vanishing, since $f$ has degree
> $n$]. Since $f \geq 0$, this means that the minimum occurs at a point
> where $f+f'+...+f^{(n)} \geq 0$.

I can't seem to reconcile this solution with my interpretation of what the problem is asking.

Comment: Your interpretation is right. But note for any function $g$ such that its minimum occurs at a point $a$ where $g(a) \ge 0$ has also the property that for any $x,$ it holds that $g(x) \ge 0.$

Comment: You understood well. Now, the degree of $g:=f+f'+\ldots+f^{[n)}$ is $n$ (even) and the leading coefficient is positive. Hence $g$ has a global minimum on $\mathbb{R}$, at $x_0$, say. You need only to check that $g(x_0) \ge 0$. This holds since $g = f+ g'$ everywhere since $f^{(n+1)}=0$, so $g(x_0)=f(x_0)$.

Comment: You've understood the problem correctly. Now, to understand the solution you just have to realise that if the minimum value of some function is non-negative, then for any point in the domain of the function the value of the function must be non-negative (being greater than the minimum).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of polynoms of given property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397973/sum-of-polynoms-of-given-property)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88260/42969, or any of these: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/88260